# Asymptotic expansion of a simple ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

I'm interested in the long-time behavior of the simple ODE

$$\dot{x} = -x^p + 1/t^q$$

with $p, q$ integers not necessarily equal and $x = x(t)$, $\dot{x} = \frac{d}{dt}x$. Furthermore, $x(0) \geq 0$ so we do not need to worry about instability with $x$ negative for $p$ even. To avoid the singularity at zero we can feel free to say $1/(t+\epsilon)^q$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, it does not matter to me. Is there a simple method to say that $x \sim 1/t^l$ for some $l$ in terms of $p$ and $q$?

Answer (score -1):

hint: Consider two options for larger $t$:

1. $|x|^p<<t^{-q}$
2. $|x|^p >> t^{-q}$

solve for each case and check for consistency.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. This will give either the rate of $\dot{x} = -x^p$ or the rate of $\dot{x} = 1/t^q$, both of which are wrong. For example, if you take $\dot{x} = -x^2 + 1/(t+\epsilon)$, you can solve this analytically in terms of Bessel functions and conclude a rate of $O(1/\sqrt{t})$. By the way this isn't homework.

Comment: There is a third option: both terms are balanced

Comment: Yes, but then we are back to the original equation, unless you just drop the $\dot{x}$.

Comment: @TheWind-UpBird That is correct though: if $p = 2$ and $q = 1$, the two dominant terms are $-x^2 + t^{-1}$, giving the first approximation $x = {t^{-1/2}}$. Then one can take $x = t^{-1/2} + A t^\alpha$ and apply the method of dominant balance again to find the next terms.